# Begin only the first chapter with roman numbering (IV)

Tags: numbering, chapters, roman-numerals

I want to include the package `acronym` in my LaTeX document. This chapter should be numbered in a roman style.

But it should not look like "I list of abbreviations", it should look like "IV list of abbreviations". It has to begin with the "IV" and only this chapter. The next chapter should be normaly begin with "1 Chapter One"

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{list of abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{i.e.}{in example}
\end{acronym}

\chapter{Chapter One}
Something, \ac{i.e.} nothing.

\chapter{Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your Minimal Working Example doesn't work - you probably mean document class `book` instead of `article`.

Comment: Any reason for having a chapter 4 (or IV) without any previous numbered chapter? In other words, why should this be number 4 and not 27 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply:

- change the formatting of the chapter numbering with `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{...}`. You can use `\Roman{chapter}` or `\arabic{chapter}` to get the capter number in (upper-case) roman or arabic literals, respectively (and similar for other representations of numbers). Of course you can also add other stuff like a trailing dot to it:

  ```
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}.}
  ```
- set the chapter counter to specific values with `\setcounter{chapter}{...}`

Do this two times, first before the list of abbreviations and second before the first chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\chapter{list of abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{i.e.}{in example}
\end{acronym}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

\chapter{Chapter One}
Something, \ac{i.e.} nothing.

\chapter{Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

## Update

Now I understand better what you want to achieve. You have an empty page layout for the front matter, so no page numbers are printed. However, you add toclines for table of contents, figures and tables manually, and they are printed with the page numbers in Roman literals, resulting in I, II and III. You want to print IV as the page number for the list of acronyms, although it is not actually on page four, however, it still has an empty page layout. Then, with the start of the first chapter, you change to a page style that displays page numbers, and reset the page number to one.

In contrast to what I suggested above, I would proceed now this way:

- Set the page number at the start of the list of acronyms to 4:

  ```
  \setcounter{page}{4}
  ```
- Use `\chapter*` for the headline of the list of acronyms, and include the "IV." by hand. This line will not be included in the list of contents.

  ```
  \chapter*{IV. \acronymtitle}
  ```
- Add the list of acronyms manually to the list of contents, without a leading "IV.":

  ```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymtitle}
  ```

Here's an example for the full code:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{4}
\newcommand{\acronymtitle}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymtitle}
\chapter*{IV. \acronymtitle}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{d.h.}{das heißt}
\end{acronym}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Erstes Kapitel}
Etwas, \ac{d.h.} nichts.

\chapter{Zweites Kapitel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Two questions: 1. is it possible to create a dot after IV? "IV. list of abbreviations"  2. My table of contents looks a 'bit weird now. See here: http://i.imgur.com/QJCZ4of.png

Comment: See edit for the trailing dot. Regarding your preview: So you actually want to have tables of contents, tables, figures and acronyms numbered as I, II, III and IV? Notice here that for the first three, I, II and III refers here to the page number, not to a section number. If the table of acronyms is not on page four, there shouldn"t be a 'IV' in it. Would you instead want to have leading numbers I, II and III for the other tables?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Actually, my first "real" chapter begins with page 1 in my table of contents. And thats good so. There are some pages before the whole stuff (cover sheet, abstract, and so on. i don't want this in my table of contents, so its fine). There is only the number 13 beside the table of acronyms, because this is page 13, if you count the cover sheet and so. But the truly page 1 is the first page of chapter 1(this work). So i just want the roman number IV beside the table of acronyms, like the first three I, II and III. It is not important in which way i can make this.

Comment: See the updated answer to achieve this. In case you don't actually use the `book` document class, leave another comment and I can adopt this solution to your actual document class.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. The updated post is the solution! One last question. My table looks now like this: http://imgur.com/b4D94e3 How can in make some dots between the abbreviation and the full name like in this example: http://imgur.com/0rnmjZc  ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about the `acronym` package.